# oneToMany copy between different entityManagers

Tags: jpa-2.0

I have a utility to copy entities between two different databases using two entity managers.

```
Query q = em1.createQuery("SELECT o FROM Holder o WHERE o.id=1");
Holder holder = (List<Holder>) q.getSingleResult();
em1.clear();
em2.getTransaction().begin();
em2.merge(holder);
em2.getTransaction().commit();
```

All works fine except oneToMany relations:

```
@Entity
public class Holder{
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "HOLDER_ID")
private Set<Piece> pieces;
}
@Entity
public class Piece{
//No mapped by to holder
}
```

The result of the operation is that holder is persisted ok and pieces are persisted as well **BUT** HOLDER_ID is null.
If I explicit a mapped by holder in Piece the joincolumn is copied but I can't change the model to be bidirectional.

Any ideas of what can be wrong? Detaching and merging in the same entityManager works fine too.
**UPDATE**: The sql generated does not contains HOLDER_ID update so 'it fails' too in the same entityManager.

(I'm using Hibernate as JPA provider).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out that the sql generated if the tables are empty is

```
1/ Insert for Holder
2/ Insert for each Piece
3/ Update to setup Holder_id in each Piece
```

But if the tables contains Holder but not pieces

```
1/ Insert for each Piece
```

That's the reason pieces losses reference to Holder.